Issue with PDF generation using iText DITO SDK(Java) and DITO file
I am using iText DITO SDK to create a PDF using a JSON and a DITO file using a Core Java application but getting a NullPointer exception on the following source code:
PdfProducer.convertTemplateFromPackage(templatePackageFile, templateName, fos, new JsonData(json));

Was debugging the code, when I observed that the filePath is null but the path has the value. Can this be a possible reason for the NullPointerException?

what should be the templatePackage file and templateName sample names?
The PDF is being generated at the path C:/output/New.pdf but its corrupted (0 KB).
code snippet:
String inputSourcePath = "C:\\output\\";
final File templatePackageFile = new File(inputSourcePath); 
final String templateName = "invoice.dito";
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/output/New.pdf")); 
final String json="{\r\n" + "    \"first_name\": \"Alexey\",\r\n"
                        + " \"last_name\": \"Subach\",\r\n"
                        + "    \"email\": \"alexey.subach@duallab.com\",\r\n"
                        + "    \"address\": \"Minsk, Belarus\",\r\n"
                        + "    \"items\": [\r\n"
                        + "        {\"item\": \"iText Core Production\", \"price\": \"1000\", \"quantity\": \"13\"},\r\n"
                        + "     {\"item\": \"iText Core QA\", \"price\": \"999\", \"quantity\": \"1\"},\r\n"
                        + "     {\"item\": \"iText Core Development\", \"price\": \"999\", \"quantity\": \"100\"},\r\n"
                        + "     {\"item\": \"iText Lego pack Star Wars\", \"price\": \"10\", \"quantity\": \"20\"},\r\n"
                        + "     {\"item\": \"iText Lego pack Harry Potter\", \"price\": \"20\", \"quantity\": \"15\"}\r\n"
                        + "    ]\r\n"
                        + "}";
PdfProducer.convertTemplateFromPackage(templatePackageFile, templateName, fos, new JsonData(json));

I was able to get the following details about the issue.
com.itextpdf.dito.sdk.output.PdfProducer - Unable to set up proper text-decoration-color handling implementation. This CSS property might work incorrectly

Has anyone integrated the DITO source code with their Java application ?  I was unable to find the related source code , so if anyone has already done this , will request to share the DITO source code repository for the following DITO version, 
com.itextpdf.dito
sdk-java
2.5.12


Was debugging the code, when I observed that the filePath is null but the path has the value. Can this be a possible reason for the NullPointerException?

No.
Have a look at the java.io.File source:
// -- Integration with java.nio.file --

private transient volatile Path filePath;

...

public Path toPath() {
    Path result = filePath;
    if (result == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            result = filePath;
            if (result == null) {
                result = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
                filePath = result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Thus, filePath is only used to cache a Path object corresponding to the File object in question. And as long as no Path object has been retrieved for the File instance, it is naturally null.
To find the cause of the NullPointerException, you had better inspect the stack trace of that exception to pinpoint the location where it is thrown.
